# Multiple WHERE from variable

Tags: php, sql

So I want to match countrycodes with regions.

```
if ($region == 'eu') {
    $country = 'nl', 'be'; etc.. etc..
}
```

Then I want to get all the users WHERE countrycode is one of the above.

```
$countryGet = $db->prepare("SELECT countrycode FROM `users` WHERE countrycode = :countrycode DESC LIMIT 100");
$countryGet->execute(array(
    ':countrycode' => $country,
));
```

Maybe I'm thinking to complicated but I cant figure out a nice way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a combination of `in_array()` and `IN()` or `FIND_IN_SET()` depending on how your DB is setup, if it isn't normalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no nice way to do this. It is an unfortunate price we have to pay for the safety of prepared statements.

Try this:

```
if( $region == "eu") {
    $countries = array("nl","be",...);
}
```

Then:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT countrycode
    FROM users
    WHERE countrycode IN (".implode(",",array_fill(0,count($countries),"?")).")
";
$countryGet = $db->prepare($sql);
$countryGet->execute($countries);
```

It gets even messier if you have additional parameters, but this should give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working with your help. It looks a bit messy indeed but I understand it and it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Terry Glad I could help :) Might be a good idea to comment the code to explain what it's doing, so you remember when you come back to it. Better still, make a function out of it ^_^